# How to change bootstrap grid system?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

When I have something like so:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
      A
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
      B
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

On a small device (mobile phone) B will break under A. 
Is there a way to break A under B without changing the sequence of the code?

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at this, might be what you're after: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-column-ordering

Answer (score 0):

Change the order of the grid columns with `.col-sm-push-*` and `.col-sm-pull-*` classes:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6">A</div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-6">B</div>
  </div>
</div>
```